# Java (or Excel) - how to align columned data that is out of order

Tags: java, excel

I have the following data:

```
    a b c d f g h i j
    a b d e f h i j
    a b c d e f j k l
    a b c d e f g h m
```

I would like to output it (into Excel for example) as follows:

```
    a b c d e f g h i j
    a b   d e f   h i j
    a b c d e f       j k l
    a b c d e f g h         m
```

In excel terms I want to shift cells across so the text matches up in columns.

NOTE: I have used alphabetic ordering for simplicity but in reality there is no such ordering - but I need to maintain the original sequencing.

Updated Example:

```
    Original Data                                                   
    a   b   c   d   f   g   h   i   j                   
    a   b   d   e   f   h   i   j                       
    a   b   c   d   e   f   j   k   l                   
    a   b   x   d   e   f   g   h   m                   

    Dougs Output                                                    
    a   b   c   d           f   g   h   i   j           
    a   b       d       e   f       h   i   j           
    a   b   c   d       e   f               j   k   l   
    a   b       d   x   e   f   g   h                   m

    My Manual Output (Required) 
    a   b   c       d       f   g   h   i   j           
    a   b           d   e   f       h   i   j           
    a   b   c       d   e   f               j   k   l   
    a   b       x   d   e   f   g   h                   m
```

Above x occurs at index 2 but d occurs at indices 2 and 3 therefore x should come before d.

Comment: If it's not alphabetical, then how do you determine the order.  In your example above, how would we know that c is before d in the output?  Is it because c occupies that position in an earlier row than d?  It might be helpful if you showed more realistic data and outputs.

Comment: @DougGlancy in this example, 'd' has a maximum index of 3 while 'c' has a maximum index of 2 so it's clear.  But if two values have the same max index then whichever one occurs first can precede later occurrences.

Comment: I think your sample is incorrect.  You show a "g" in row 1 in the output but not in the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it in Java.  There is a custom compare which looks at the max and min indices of each values and sorts on that.  Then I printed them out to screen.

**Note my data is in a HashMap for reasons not explained here but it could have easily been in a simple List.

**Note excuse my inexperienced coding practices.

@Doug-Glancy if you are able to do with in VB it would be great!

ValueComparator.java

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;

public class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private Map<String, Integer[]> base;

    public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer[]> m) {
        this.base = m;
    }

    public int compare(String so1, String so2) {

        // get the max and min indices from each data peice
        Integer[] o1 = base.get(so1);
        Integer[] o2 = base.get(so2);

        // compare their min index first
        if (o1[0] < o2[0]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (o1[0] == o2[0]) { //if they are the same
            if ( o1[1] < o2[1]) { // then look at the max index
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }                   
        }
        else { 
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

App.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import localhost.ValueComparator;


public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        // create a list to store our original data
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> keyValuePairs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // add the data to the list
        HashMap<String, String> a = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        a.put("a", "1"); a.put("b", "1"); a.put("c", "1"); a.put("d", "1"); a.put("f", "1"); a.put("g", "1"); a.put("h", "1"); a.put("i", "1"); a.put("j", "1");
        keyValuePairs.add(a);

        HashMap<String, String> e = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        e.put("a", "1"); e.put("b", "1"); e.put("d", "1"); e.put("e", "1"); e.put("f", "1"); e.put("h", "1"); e.put("i", "1"); e.put("j", "1");
        keyValuePairs.add(e);

        HashMap<String, String> b = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        b.put("a", "1"); b.put("b", "1"); b.put("c", "1"); b.put("d", "1"); b.put("e", "1"); b.put("f", "1"); b.put("j", "1"); b.put("k", "1"); b.put("l", "1");
        keyValuePairs.add(b);

        HashMap<String, String> c = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        c.put("a", "1"); c.put("b", "1"); c.put("x", "1"); c.put("d", "1"); c.put("e", "1"); c.put("f", "1"); c.put("g", "1"); c.put("h", "1"); c.put("m", "1");
        keyValuePairs.add(c);

        // create a map to store the max and min indices
        Map<String, Integer[]> m = new HashMap<String, Integer[]>();

        Integer curpos = new Integer(0);

        // loop through the data and find the max and min indices of each data (key)
        for ( Map<String,String> s : keyValuePairs) {
            curpos = 0;
            for ( String t : s.keySet() ) {

                if ( !m.containsKey(t) ){
                    // if its the first time to see the data, just add its current index as max and min
                    m.put(t,new Integer[] {curpos, curpos});

                }
                else {
                    // check if index is lower than existing minimum
                    Integer[] i = m.get(t);
                    if ( i[0] > curpos) {
                        m.put(t, new Integer[] {curpos, i[1]});
                    }
                    //check if index is greater than current maximum
                    if ( curpos > i[1] ) {
                        m.put(t, new Integer[] {i[0], curpos});
                    }
                }
                curpos++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The unsorted data");

        for ( HashMap<String,String> h : keyValuePairs ) {
            for ( String s : h.keySet() ) {
                System.out.print(" " + s + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("\n");

        // Sort the data using our custom comparator
        ValueComparator com = new ValueComparator(m);
        List<String> toSort = new LinkedList<String>(m.keySet());
        Collections.sort(toSort, com);

        System.out.println("The sorted data");

        for ( HashMap<String,String> h : keyValuePairs) {

            for ( String s : toSort ) {
                if ( h.containsKey(s) ) {
                    System.out.print(s + " ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it.  This relies on the fact that you can't add duplicate values to a `collection`.  The trick is to parse through the source data in the right order.  I interpret that to be down through each cell in a column and then over to the next column.  The collection then contains the first instance of each item as found in that search order.

The code requires two sheets, one with the source and a target sheet to contain the output.  In this case I set `wsSource` and `wsTarget` to the first two sheets in the workbook with the code, but you can alter that as you wish.

You can change the definition of `rng`.  As long as there's nothing else on the source sheet, the code will determine the last row and last column of data.  This is done by the lines with `Find` in them:

```
Sub Rearrange()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim coll As Collection
Dim wsTarget As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim SourceLastCol As Long

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set rng = wsSource.Range("A1:i4")    'change to suit

Set coll = New Collection
SourceLastRow = rng.Cells.Find("*", rng.Cells(1), xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
SourceLastCol = rng.Cells.Find("*", rng.Cells(1), xlValues, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
'cycle through the cells in the range down through each column from left to right
For i = 1 To SourceLastCol
    For j = 1 To SourceLastRow
        Set cell = wsSource.Cells(j, i)
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            'can only add an item once - no duplicates
            coll.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'Clear and re-load wsTarget
wsTarget.Cells.Clear
For i = 1 To coll.Count
    For j = 1 To SourceLastRow
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsSource.Cells(j, 1).EntireRow, coll(i)) = 1 Then
            wsTarget.Cells(j, i) = coll(i)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Doug.  However I have added an updated example which fails.

Comment: @user1681739 I knew you would :)!

Comment: @user1681739 I think I still don't quite understand the requirement, and I'm going to wish you good luck.  Perhaps the code above will get you started.